# How to copy certain row details into new workssheet if multiple condition is met, using VBA?

Tags: vba

I'm trying to copy a row of data from one sheet to another if column "I" contains a certain letter (or phrase) and if "D" column (dates) is between, january, february and so on.

For instance, the data I'd like to copy is on a sheet called "Clients" and if column I contains the letter "T" then I'd like that data to auto-import into the next sheet called "Tax - Pending" with all those clients in the month of January.

PLEASE NOTE I ONLY WANT TO COPY THE ROW's CERTAIN DETAILS.

I have found VBA answer as but it only works for one criteria.

```
Sub CopyRow()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim x As Long, MaxRowList As Long, S As String, wsSource As Worksheet, wsTarget As Worksheet

    Set wsSource = ThisWorkbook.WorkSheets("Clients")
    Set wsTarget = ThisWorkbook.WorkSheets("Tax - Pending")
    iCol = 1
    MaxRowList = wsSource.Cells(Rows.Count, iCol).End(xlUp).Row
    For x = 3 To MaxRowList
        If InStr(1, wsSource.Cells(x, 9), "T") Then
            wsTarget.Rows(x).Value = wsSource.Rows(x).Value
        End If
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: What is precisely the other criteria?

Comment: If column D is within January 2017, Feberuary 2017, it changes month by month. (Report)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check if the date at column `D` is within the current month, change your test

> `If InStr(1, wsSource.Cells(x, 9), "T") Then`

into this:

```
If InStr(1, wsSource.Cells(x, 9), "T") And Month(wsSource.Cells(x, 4)) = Month(Now) Then
```

Comment: Thank you! it worked. But what if i don't want all the field in the rows to be copied? just the specific ones?

Comment: Ah, do you want to copy only the values in columns I and D?

Comment: No, actually i want to copy the rows but not all of the row details for example i only want to copy the name column, code, in the given row.. like that

Comment: no problem. you can copy the cells one by one instead of coying the whole row. Easy. For example, to copy column `A`  :   `wsTarget.Cells(x. "A").Value = wsSource.Cells(x. "A").Value` and so on
`

Comment: For x = 2 To MaxRowList
   
    If InStr(1, wsSource.Cells(x, 21), "SEO") And Month(wsSource.Cells(x, 4)) = Month(Previous) Then
    AfterLastTarget = wsTarget.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    wsTarget.Rows(AfterLastTarget + 1).Value = wsSource.Rows(x).Value
End If

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133848/discussion-between-chels-and-a-s-h).